# Can not Bind Data DropDownListFor with ViewBag and SelectListItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have trouble with my `MVC DropDownListFor`. I tried to get Data source for this `dropdownlist` from `ViewBag` as below:

This is from Controller.

```
 ViewBag.Titles = new List<SelectListItem>() { 
     new SelectListItem(){
           Value="1",
           Text="Mr."
      },
      new SelectListItem(){
           Value="2",
           Text="Ms."
      },
      new SelectListItem(){
           Value= "3",
           Text= "Miss"
      },
      new SelectListItem(){
            Value="4",
            Text="Mrs.",
      },
      new SelectListItem(){
           Value= "5",
           Text= "Prof"
 }};
```

This is from Edit View:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TitleId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Titles, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I tried to edit one record from database which has TitleId=2 but when this view was displayed, dropdownlist is always selected the first option ( TitleId=1).

How can I set this dropdownlist to be selected value is 2?

Thank you.

Comment: First its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TitleId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Titles, new { @class = "form-control" })` - there is no point in creating a 2nd identical `SelectList` from the 1st one. What do you mean _can not bind TitleId from database_? Where is your code that sets the property?

Comment: where do you have the data from database ?

Comment: I have Person table ( which has TitleId field).  I will have some person who has TitleId=2 or 3...

Comment: You need to show the relevant code - the controller method that return this view (how and where do you set the model and return it to the view)

Comment: Why in the world did you accept a wrong answer that throws an exception, and that has nothing to do with your issue. If the value of `TitleId` is `2` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view, then the 2nd option will be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the different property to bind, please check again: with Model is having "TitleId" while Source of Dropdownlist has selectedValue is "Value". Please try to get source for DropdownlistFor from different list which has same name with Model property (TitleId). You can see below example:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TitleId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Titles, "TitleId", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: `ViewBag.Titles` is typeof `List<SelectListItem>()` and `SelectListItem` does not contain a property named `TitleId` and this code throws an exception.

Comment: Yes, I mean ViewBag.Title should be set from other source, should not use SelectListItem any more Please read again my answer " Please try to get source for DropdownlistFor from different list ", I meant different list type ( such as: get from other Model what has "TitleId" property.

Comment: What do you mean _should not use SelectListItem_? - of course OP should be it.

Comment: yeah, I meant that because of SelectListItem is class has "Value" and "Text" Properties for binding data. this class not be matched same name with key of Model( in this case it's TitleId).

Comment: What? The code just needs to be as I noted in the first comment to the question. And if the value of `TitleId` is set in the GET method before its passed to the view, then the correct option will be selected.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I completely set it from GET method but it still not passed to the view. I followed suggestion from Minh Bui, I created a table in database to store all data of Title, after that create Title Model and biding to View. it's resolved.

Comment: @MichaelCopley. Sorry, but that's nonsense - if the value of `TitleId` is `2` and you have passed the model to the view then the second option **will** be selected (and whether you hard code the values of use a database to store them is irrelevant). Either you did not set the value correctly, or you did not pass the model to the view. And take note of my first comment (generating a 2nd identical `SelectList` from the existing one is pointless). Or maybe `TitleId` is a field and not a property.